# C# Read Serial Port Data based on Standard way

Tags: c#, serial-port

its some years i have a software that work with truck scales read data from weight indicator via RS232 serial port and in all devices i just used serial port data received method i want to know whats the standard way to read these data from a serial port i just attached a document from weight indicator company that mentioned the data format [image: Data format manual]. i dont want to read data and then play with char to replace it with blank or any other process i just want its Standard way if anyone help me in this section i will be happy its the output of my serial port which the target is the middle number 10

```
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0    10     0
-ip0     0     0
>ip0     0     0
>ip0     0     0
>ip0     0     0
>ip0     0     0
>ip0     0     0
```

> ip0     0     0

Comment: Programming is so flexible, not just serial ports, that there wouldn't be a standard way to specify no requirements. They are influenced by various factors. All you have presented is a notification data format, which is similar to consulting system development from scratch. Please embody it as a programmatic problem appropriate for the questions on this site. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class to use the serial port in C#. The data received by the SerialPort class is of byte type and can be converted to string type.

According to your description, each data frame you receive has a fixed length. You can add a processing of parsing the data frame to the receiving function. For example, when data of a certain length is received, it is converted into a data frame, and the extra string On to the next analysis. If the data is not of fixed length, a terminator can be added to the data frame to determine.

The data frames of serial communication are defined according to their actual needs, and the format of the data frames is uncertain, so the parsing process needs to be completed by yourself.

hope to help you